# Jordan Canonical Form Materials

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, jordan-normal-form

I'm in high school and I study for the mathematical olympiad (I'm in 11th grade)and I want to learn about Jordan Canonical form and I have a very hard time finding good materials on the internet. Can anyone recommend a good material? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have enough knowledge about what is **Rank ?**, what is **Kernel ?**, what is **geometric multiplicity ?** etc. etc. for a matrix. i.e., I want to know your depth about the basic things before starting the Jordan Canonical form .

Comment: I know about the rank,the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.I dont know about Kernel nor about geometric multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

As per our discussion on the comment section, I realize that first of all you have to check some examples. After that you learn the theory.

So here are some references

$1.~~$ https://www.math.ucla.edu/~jlindquist/115B/JCF.pdf

$2.~~$ http://www.numbertheory.org/courses/MP274/jordex.pdf

$3.~~$  [Jordan Canonical form (Brilliant)](https://brilliant.org/wiki/jordan-canonical-form/)

First read **Ref. $\bf1$** and **Ref. $\bf2$** after that **Ref. $\bf3$**. You can also follow some YouTube videos.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @nmasanta The link for the first reference is not working. If you have any idea about the new link, it would be great if you could update it.

Comment: @mathstudent The link may had been deleted by the admin of that link. However you can try this: https://mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211sp/m211txtch6.pdf

Comment: @nmasanta Great! Thanks.